# iOS Swift: Refresh table view but not footer

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a tableview with a custom footer view. The footer view is a search box that is filtering the tableview. On each keystroke the table data is changing and I would like to update the tableview accordingly. The problem is if I use `reloadData()` I lose the state of the search box and the keyboard is dismissed. I tried to use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` but because the table data is changing and the total number of rows is being reduced I get an exception when I try to reload a row that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Pull out the footer into a separate, sibling view to the table view, instead.

Comment: Instead of having a custom footer view on the table view, make it a separate view. This way, refreshing the table view won't affect the view at all. :)

Comment: Note that this would require that you use a `UIViewController` subclass instead of `UITableViewController` subclass.

Comment: The footer view gives me behavior that I want, specifically the sticky footer behavior. Is there no way good way to fresh the table minus the footer?

Comment: Have you tried using `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` See `UITableView` docs-- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/

Comment: Yes, the footer view is part of the section I believe. Maybe I could create a second section with no rows but only a footer

Comment: Yeah, this is why I suggest pulling it out altogether-- it quickly can become hacky otherwise.